# Design better text file format for reading mixed type data of variable length

Tags: c#, text-files, vb6-migration

I am designing a text file format to be read in C#. I have a need to store types: int, double and string on a single line. I'm planning to use a .CSV format so the file can be manually opened and read. A particular record may have say 8 known types, then a variable number of "indicator" combinations of either (string, int, double) or (string, int, double, double), and some lines may include no "indicators". Thus, each record is may be of variable length.

In VB6 I would just input the data, split the data, into a variant array, then determine the number of elements on that line in the array, and use the ***VarType function to determine if the final "indicator" variables are string, int, or double and parse the field accordingly.

There may be a better way to design a text file and that may be the best solution. If so I'm interested in hearing ideas. I have searched but found no questions that specifically talk about reading variable length lines of text with mixed type into C#.

If a better format is not forthcoming, is there a way to duplicate the VB6 VarType function within C# as described two paragraphs above***? I can handle the text file reading and line splitting easily in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I agree with Keith's suggestion to use Xml or JSON. You are reinventing a wheel here. [This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szzyf24s%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) has an introductory example of how to serialize objects to a file and some links to more info.

If you need to stick with your own file format and custom serialization/deserialization however take a look at the [Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) class, as well as the various [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) methods which hang off of the intrinsic value types like int and double.

Comment: Same question regarding the ability to manually open and read Xml or JSON formats like a text file - is it possible? I'm familiar with the Convert class and TryParse. If you don't know if a field is string, int or double, is there a way to check the split string  type before attempting conversion?

Comment: Look at the xmlserializer class. It will handle type conversion for you

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I got some simple demo code working with xmlserializer. I need an array of classes to be stored in a single file. Is the best way to create a container class to house the array of classes so it all gets stored into a single object / single file?

Comment: Using a container class seemed to work and was extraordinarily painless with an array of classes. Really fantastic!

Comment: Yeah it is pretty slick. Will do entire object graphs pretty effortlessly

Answer (score 2):

you could use either json or xml as they are well supported in .NET and have automatic serialization capabilities

Comment: Do either of the formats mentioned support the ability to manually open and read the contents like a text file?